# Can't Find A Way to Fix External Link on Github

Tags: html, github, hyperlink, href

I published a website (a project of my online course) which have social media button at footer area. I linked these with href but when I publish it on github, instead of directing me to "www.twitter.com", it directs me to "...github.io/www.twitter.com". What is the best way to fix this?

My code looks like below;

```
<footer id="footer">
    <a href="https:/www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter footer-social">  </i></a>
    <a href="https:/www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f footer-social">  </i></a>
    <a href="https:/www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram footer-social"> </i></a>
    <a href="https:/www.gmail.com" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-envelope footer-social">  </i></a>
    <p class="p-footer">© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

</footer>
```

Also you can check published version from here: https://tayfunilbakan.github.io/tindog/

Comment: you need to write ```https://www.twitter.com``` rather than ```https:/www.twitter.com``` (notice one slash vs double slash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your href values are missing an extra forward slash. Make sure they start with `https://` as opposed to `https:/`.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot!